# Installing Horde on CentOS 6 cant find files

Tags: lamp, webmail, centos

I am trying to install Horde on a clean install of CentOS on a vps. The install and config seemed to go ok but when I try and open Horde through my domain (example.com/horde) I get nothing, the page loads but it is blank.

When I run the test script I get this.

```
Could not find Horde's framework libraries in the following path(s):
/var/www/horde/lib:.:/usr/share/php. Please read horde/docs/INSTALL 
for information on how to install these libraries.
```

The files are definitely there and all permissions seem to be OK. Please help!!

Results for: ls -l /var/www/horde/lib /usr/share/php
/usr/share/php:
total 0

/var/www/horde/lib:
total 116

drwxr-x--- 3 root root  4096 Oct 31 12:28 Ajax

-rw-r----- 1 root root 27496 Oct 31 12:28 Api.php

-rw-r----- 1 root root 12180 Oct 31 12:28 Application.php

drwxr-x--- 3 root root  4096 Oct 31 12:28 Block

-rw-r----- 1 root root  1039 Oct 31 12:28 Bundle.php

drwxr-x--- 4 root root  4096 Oct 31 12:28 LoginTasks

drwxr-x--- 3 root root  4096 Oct 31 12:28 Prefs

-rw-r----- 1 root root 38377 Oct 31 12:28 Test.php

drwxr-x--- 3 root root  4096 Oct 31 12:28 Tree

drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 Oct 31 12:28 View

-rw-r----- 1 root root  2495 Oct 31 12:28 core.php

drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 Oct 31 12:28 tests

Comment: Post the results of "ls -l /var/www/horde/lib /usr/share/php" please?

Comment: Pleaes see edits

Comment: Ummm, where is your "Horde" subdirectory, which will in turn have Form, Http, IMAP, etc subdirectories of its own? Do you need to add /usr/share/horde/lib/Horde to your path?

Comment: Well i have wiped my VPS and started over many times. I was following one tut that installed Horde via yum, in that case all the horde files were in /usr/share/horde, I have also installed via  pear and installed to /var/www/horde. In that case I dont get any missing file errors I only get 403 you do not have permission. Even though i have run the permissions script from horde and also made sure apache was owner of www/horde and made sure horde.conf was correct. Is there anywhere you can point me for up to date install info, I am happy to start from scratch again, just nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

- check your `/var/log/httpd/` files for errors
- usually you can find which files cannot be found in example Horde/Autoloader
- find them ( `find / |grep Autoloader` )
- in example `/usr/share/pear/Horde/Autoloader` so `/usr/share/pear` should be added to `include_path` of `php`
- to do so just edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/horde.conf` and adjust `include_path` value